# ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable not being loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, environment-variables, aspnetcoretemplatepack

I cant get the environment variable to load. I check the variable like this:

```
 Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

In my development environment it works fine, I get the text: "Development". That is due to the fact that I have that setting directly in my project file.

In my Staging environment it always return null or empty string, hence defaulting to Production.

I have tried the following:

1. Entering an environment variable manually:
   [image]
2. Setting it in a command prompt
3. I have then restarted my entire server

It is just always empty. Can any one see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not having this problem anymore, and this problem was found several versions back.
It seems that the aspnet core 2.1 is very stable and ready for production.